# \begin{figure} and \framebreak not working in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, graphics, includegraphics

I'm trying to display two images in different slides using \framebreak.

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Title}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{"table5a".png}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\framebreak

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{"table5a".png}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}
```

It only displays the first image. Any idea about how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the quotation marks in the file name. So change it from `"table5a".png` to `table5a.png`.

And the frame has to be closed.

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Title}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{table5a.png}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\framebreak

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{table5a.png}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: +1, GREAT answer! I looked at your profile because I was curious. I notice you "followed" my Materials Modeling stack exchange proposal but did not yet "commit". At this point we need all the help we can get, so I wonder if you would mind committing? https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=MTRlZjUyNGY3MGY4ZWY5ZWZkZGVlNmY0NzY5ZjEzN2NjMjNlZTIwMjU0MWU0MDRjNjM2YjIxZmUxNGVhMWZlMHGM23pUo7y5cQ0jl0rBbYtJLWEPnIuIsvgjQSnSfyMm0. We would appreciate it a lot!